# Is Drupal contact form securely encrypted?

Tags: emails

In Germany, it is mandatory to by law to use secure contact forms (secured by TLS for example) when you are a website owner. Is the Drupal 7 contact form secure in this regard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. No form, in any website, is inherently "secure" or encrypted. If your requirement is to serve and submit the form over TLS, you'll need to set that up on your server/host as a separate task.

Once you have, Drupal will happily serve any page over https, and submit forms in the same manner.

The only thing you might want to consider from a Drupal point of view is to un-comment the lines in the default .htaccess which force-upgrade all requests to https. If your server isn't Apache that'll have to be done elsewhere.

Comment: Your answer suggest to force all requests to use https – what about just forcing the contact form? Is there a possibilty?

Comment: Sort of, but it's pretty awkward. You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/securepages, but it hasn't been updated in a long time now. Given the current state of the internet full https is the way to go